# Query to retrieve column values as rows from table which has duplicate rows in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which has records in the following format:

```
OrderID | CategoryID | Percentage
-----------------------------------------
 Order1       1           50
 Order1       2          100
 Order1       3           70
 Order2       1           85
 Order2       2           75
 Order2       3          100
 Order3       1           50
 Order3       2           60
 Order3       3           80
```

Each order has multiple categories and each category has a percentage corresponding to that order.

I want to display it in the following format:

```
OrderID | Category1_%  |  Category2_%  |  Category3_%
-------------------------------------------------------
Order1        50            100             70
Order2        85             75            100
Order3        50             60             80
```

How do I write a query in SQL Server 2008 to retrieve percentages for each category of each (distinct) order? Please help.

**Edit:**
    Orders table

```
ID      |  StartDate  
--------------------
Order1     1/1/2016         
Order2     10/1/2015           
Order3     10/5/2016
```

The query which I executed is:

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max)

Declare @startDate datetime

set @startDate='1/1/2015'

Declare @endDate datetime

set @endDate= '10/1/2016'

Select  @SQL = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName('Category'+cast(CategoryID as varchar(25))+'_%') From OrdersData Order By 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'')

Select  @SQL = 'Select [OrderID],' + @SQL +'
From (Select OrderID,Percentage,Item=''Category''+cast(CategoryID as varchar(25))+''_%'' from OrdersData join Orders on Orders.ID =OrdersData.OrderID 
WHERE Orders.StartDate >= '+ ***convert(nvarchar(25), @startDate, 121)*** + ' and GCWR.StartDate <= '+  ***convert(nvarchar(25), @endDate, 121)*** +') A
Pivot (max(Percentage) For Item in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'

Exec(@SQL);
```

When I execute, I get an error 'Incorrect syntax near '00'.' How do I call the datetime values in the above query to display the results? Please let me know.

Comment: Look up for `Pivot/Cross tab/Conditional Aggregate` in google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you need to go dynamic

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) 
Select  @SQL = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName('Category'+cast(CategoryID as varchar(25))+'_%') From YourTable Order By 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = 'Select [OrderID],' + @SQL +'
                From (Select OrderID,Percentage,Item=''Category''+cast(CategoryID as varchar(25))+''_%'' from YourTable) A
                Pivot (max(Percentage) For Item in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Returns

[image]

> **Edit - Updated with StartDate**

```
Declare @Date1 datetime = '2015-01-01'
Declare @Date2 datetime = '2016-10-01'

Declare @SQL varchar(max) 
Select  @SQL = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName('Category'+cast(CategoryID as varchar(25))+'_%') From YourTable Where cast(StartDate as date) between @Date1 and @Date2  Order By 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = 'Select [OrderID],' + @SQL +'
                From (Select OrderID,Percentage,Item=''Category''+cast(CategoryID as varchar(25))+''_%'' from YourTable Where cast(StartDate as date) between '''+convert(varchar(10),@Date1,120)+''' and '''+convert(varchar(10),@Date2,120)+''') A
                Pivot (max(Percentage) For Item in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: I executed this query using join, but I am not able to retrieve any rows when I include dates in the where condition, it may be because of the wrong conversion format of dates, I tried convert, cast methods but was not able to retrieve...Can you please see the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Select OrderID, [1] as [Category1_%], [2] as [Category2_%],[3] as [Category3_%] 
From [TableName]
PIVOT (MAX([Percentage]) FOR [CategoryID] IN ([1],[2],[3])) myPivot
```

This assumes that you know all the possible values in the categoryID field and that each CategoryID an OrderID combination has a single percentage value.